# How to call datagrid sortification from a asp:button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I have a datagrid which reads all songs from a directory and generate rows. I wrote and the datagrid sortification which sort by song name on ASC or DESC the only way to call sortification is to press the link in the header. But I whant to call sortification command from a asp:button, how can I do?

Comment: Ow... sa I asked from my phone. Later I will share and the code. But I whanted to find out is it possible to call the datagrid sortification command from other control?

Comment: dude, is paging enabled in your grid? also is it a datagrid or gridview?

Comment: As I told DataGrid! no, no paging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the asp.net command button's click event you can do sortting using the DataView

e.g:

```
DataView myDataView = new DataView(mybll.GetItemsOrdered()); 
myDataView.Sort = sortExpression + " DESC"; 
GridView.DataSource = myDataView; 
GridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: Yes that works I used your example up bellow is code I wrote!

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can try with this code that invoke delegate

```
void SortGrid(Object sender, DataGridSortCommandEventArgs e) 
{
}

void Btn_Click(Object sender,EventArgs e)
{
        SortGrid(YourDataGrid, new DataGridSortCommandEventArgs{SortExpression = value, CommandSource = value});
    //You pass yours values
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sort.aspx).

The strategy would be to save the current sort of the grid somewhere you can retrieve.  Then, when the button is clicked, you want to modify that sort expression according to whatever logic you need, and send that sort expression back to the grid to sort it (2nd link).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The code that had to slve my problem:

```
protected void SortBySizeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataView myDataView = new DataView(GetFiles()); //GetFiles is protected DataTable that populates my DataGrid :)
    myDataView.Sort = "size " + " DESC"; // size is the SortExpression
    dgFile.DataSource = myDataView;
    dgFile.DataBind();
}
```

thats all! :)